# Как вывести строку ошибки в модуле Python

Tags: python

Как вывести строку ошибки в модуле?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте:

```
try:
    import module_name
except BaseException as e:
    print(e.__class__.__name__, str(e), sep=':')
```